# Window Controls Not Seeming Properly When Converting Xubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu

Tags: unity, 16.04, xubuntu

I wanted to remove `xubuntu-desktop` and install `ubuntu-desktop`. I did not want to do a fresh-install since I have a lot of packages and configurations. I firstly did:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then, applied [this documentation](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu) to completely remove Xubuntu. I know, some packages in Xubuntu 16.04 does not exist, so I customized the code based on "Unable to locate x package" error.

Everything went well, login screen is okay, borders are okay, Unity environment is okay etc. However, one thing is not! Some window controls are strangely glitched or does not exist, as it can be seen below:

[image]

As you can see, tabs, breadcrumbs, minus-plus buttons does not seem properly. I also run across on-off button does not seem properly too.

Now, is there are way to overcome this?

#### Edit 1

Also right click menus do not have borders.

---

## Environment

- Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Install Unity Tweak Tool and change your theme to Ambiance.

Comment: Okay, that is a solution. However, I also want to keep Arc theme.

Comment: Play around with combinations. Most of the time, one DE just isn't compatible with another's themes, and there isn't much you can do beyond editing the theme yourself.